# Import historical Apache log file into Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

Is it possible, somehow, to load an Apache log into Google Analytics for analysis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't import historical data, but there is a Universal Analytics project in beta enabling you to use GA as your warehouse.
Anyway, looks like Piwik has Apache2Piwik import scripts included in distro http://piwik.org/blog/2011/06/import-log-files-piwik/ - you should try this one.

Answer (score 2):

You can't load logs into Google Analytics. The service isn't offered and the data types are different - Analytics collects data from the client side while Apache logs are server side.

To analyse Apache logs, there are a number of tools that you can operate yourself such as [AWStats](http://awstats.sourceforge.net) (on your server) or [Apache Log Viewer](http://www.apacheviewer.com/) (on the desktop). If you are really keen on a Web Application there are a couple of suggestions on this [old SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475827/online-based-apache-web-log-analyzer-by-submitting-just-the-raw-logfile).